# How to merge multiple files to one, placed next to each other in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, cs6, merge

I have a bunch of QR codes and a bunch of serial numbers associated with these codes. I need to print a lot of tickets, each having a different QR code and corresponding serial number on them.

So far I had success to generate those tickets, by using variables and datasets, with help of [this awesome tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCBrK8tZAXQ)  and the script mentioned in it.

I end up with hundreds of files, each having one artboard, with one ticket in it.

What I need is a file with artboards of A3 size, so I can create a PDF file with multiple pages for print. Obviously, on each of these A3 artboards should be as many tickets as possible.

Comment: Does the order matter?

Answer (score 1):

(Didn't watch the video)....

Not sure if it'll work for you, but you can create a multi-page PDF merely using Acrobat...

In Acrobat, choose `File > Create > Combine Files into Single PDF` and choose your separate .ai files. They should be combined into a multi-page PDF.